# Using the mv command - file deleted?

Tags: unix, mv

This is probably a very stupid question, but is it possible that files can be deleted with the "mv" command? 
I'm asking because I when I was attempting to move a file up to its parent directory, I accidentally typed one "." too many and now I can't find my file.

So instead of:

> $ mv myfile.txt ..

I had put:

> $ mv myfile.txt ...

Now my file is gone. Did I delete it accidentally, and is it possible to get it back at all?

Thanks!

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming and programmers tools related questions, not general operating system or computer support questions. For those, there are other [se] sites like [su] and [AskUbuntu](http://www.askubuntu.com). Voting to close and migrate to [su] where it's more appropriate, as you didn't mention the specific *nix version or distro. Good luck. :-)

Comment: Whoops sorry about that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your file has been renamed to "..." do an `ls -a` to see dot files.

Try `mv ... ../myfile.txt` to get do what you originally wanted.

Answer (score 2):

you file is now named as `...`, check it with `ls -al` in your current dir.

Answer (score 2):

On UNIX systems, file names starting with a dot are hidden from directory listings by default.

```
ls -lA
```

will display dot files.

You can rename the file back

```
mv ... myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Your file is now called `...` and is not visible thru the simple `ls` command.
Use `ls -a` to make "system" files (starting with a dot) visible or rename it back `mv ... your_file`.

And to answer the title-question:

Yes and no.

It' s not possible, but moving the file to `/dev/null` will delete it as well. :D